# Sort NSTableView bound to NSArrayController based on a undisplayed value

Tags: objective-c, sorting, binding, nstableview

I have a `NSArrayController` with Objects (Mutable dictionaries) taht contain 2 values for each entry. The values are "keyword" and "order".

The `NSArrayController` is bound to a NSTableView that has only one column and is displaying the "keyword" value.

I would need to sort the table based on "order".

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
[keywordscontroller.arrangedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

But the order in the `NSTableView` is not updating. what am I missing?

---EDIT ---

sample of how it is sorting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing the result of your call to `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors` and so, you will never have access to it.

However, since you already are using an `NSArrayController`, why not just use the `- (void)setSortDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors` method of your `NSArrayController` and then reference the contents of the array using `- (id)arrangedObjects`?

---

custom sort descriptor for string with numeric comparison

```
[keywordscontroller setSortDescriptor:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: sorry, pretty green here, not sure i am following. could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Ok, i think i got what you mean. The probelm i have now is that "order" is of type Double, but the sorting treats it as string. any idea on how to declare it as double?

Comment: When you say, 'treats it as a string', what exactly do you mean? Can you provide an example?

Comment: sure! if i have the values as double "1.0, 5.0, 10.0" i would expect them to be sorted exactly like i wrote them here. from the smalles to the highest. for some reason it is sorting them like this: 1.0, 10.0, 5.0 since the first digit of 10.0 is a 1 it comes before the 5.0

Comment: I see. That is not something I have run into before, but appears to be not entirely unusual. The values being compared are for sure being stored as instances of `NSNumber`, correct? If you are for sure they are being stored as such, then you could try writing a custom `NSSortDescriptor` using the `+ (id)sortDescriptorWithKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending comparator:(NSComparator)cmptr` (see my edit above).

Comment: thanks! trying it but there are 2 errors in your sting.. trying to figure out where..

Comment: @user2452250 oops!  forgot the `*` after `NSString`.

Comment: fixed this way: `  NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];` THANKS for your help on this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54394/discussion-between-user2452250-and-andrew-monshizadeh).

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to get it working as expected.